# how to show the UI Slider value in two different fields?

Tags: jquery, uislider

i am tying to show the UI range slider value in input box. i have done this but i want show the same value on another  also, that span is in another .

here i am getting the slider value on this input box but the same value must reflect on another div's  also.

How do i do it , help me out of this

```js
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 10,
    min: 210,
    max: 850,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $(".inputCount").val(ui.value);
        $(".borrowMonth").val(ui.value);
    }
});
$(".inputCount").change(function () {
    $("#slider").slider("value",this.value);
});
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
<label>£</label>
<input type="text" value="200" class="inputCount"/>

<div class="borrowMonth">£ <span>200</span> </div>
```

Comment: post your complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using the wrang method - "val" for the element. And you need chnage the selector. This is working variant:

```
$(".borrowMonth span").text(ui.value);
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s1hfkgr2/

Comment: if that .borrowMonth span will be where ever div's it will find and work know?

Comment: If you do not want to depend on the name/type of the element you can for example add special class for it. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jcgL69do/1/

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/MD3mX/1813/

The change has to be done here:

```
$(".borrowMonth span").html(ui.value);
```

Refer to the span inside your .borrowMonth class and pass the value as html, not as val. A span doesn't have a val attribute,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `text()` instead of `val()`

And you need to select you span tag instead of div

```
$(".borrowMonth span").text(ui.value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uza54ku/